# Fourier Transform of the given generalised function

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

One of a problem requires the following equation to be true.
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\; f(x)\;e^{\pi\iota x^2}\;e^{-2\pi\iota ux}\;dx = F(u)\; e^{-\pi\iota u^2}$$ where $F(u)$ is the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$
If this is true, can anyone please provide a proof.

Comment: If $f$ is arbitrary, this isn't true. The correct relations for the FT with the kernel $e^{-2 \pi i u x}$ are
$$\mathcal F[f g] = \mathcal F[f] * \mathcal F[g], \\
\mathcal F[x \mapsto e^{\pi i x^2}](u) =
e^{\pi i/4} e^{-\pi i u^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is false.
If you take $f(x) = g(x) e^{-i\pi x^2}$, then the left is the Fourier transform of $g$ while the right is $g(x) e^{-2 i\pi x^2}$

Comment: Sorry, there was a small mistake. The function in RHS is actually the Fourier Transform of $f(x)$